# Is it appropriate to create a filename using "paste" inside of file.path?

Tags: r

`?file.path` indicates that this function is designed to be faster than `paste`, so I am concerned that writing

```
dirname <- "/path/to/myfile/"
file.path(dirname, paste(output, ".csv", sep = ""))
```

is missing the point.

Is it?

Comment: `file.path` is just a bit smarter in the specific domain of file paths: it will stick in separators if they are required.

Comment: Also, it doesn't deal with separators, so what you've done looks fine. It might be marginally quicker to use `paste0`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`file.path` has some special functions for dealing with stuff inside R's library, as well as working across platforms.

For the purposes of writing `csv` files, saving plots as `pngs` and such, I believe that `paste` is a better option because it bypasses the "middleman". Using `paste` within `file.path` is not really a problem (if you need the functionality of `file.path`), because any speed differences will be undetectable.